# tapping didSelectRowAtIndexPath when field comes from sqlite database

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, uitableview

I have a uitableview that is populated with data from my sqlite database.
As a result I am trying to load a newview when i tap the first cell whose content is "test". 
So i tried the following code

```
if ([[patients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString:@"test"])
{do this }
```

but i get the error `-[Patient isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` 
Would love some help in how i access my database string to compare them too the value when i click.
Thanks
P.S   this is how i add my values to my uitableview `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
Patient *as = [patients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = as.region;
```

This code gives the same error as well

```
Patient *as = [patients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if ([as.region isEqualToString:@"TEST"])
```

Comment: `[Patient isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector` tells you that you used an operation (`isEqualToString`) which the class `Patient` does not implement.  Most often this is because the object being used in the call is not the type that you thought it was.  The thing to do is to assign the result of `[patients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` to a temporary variable and then either log that or examine it at a breakpoint to see what it is.  (You can then use that temp as the object for `isEqualToString` call -- coding everything on one line *does not* make it more efficient.)

Comment: @HotLicks if you look at the last code i posted in my orginal message, i added a breakpoint on the second line and i see.self,indexPath and patients. in indexPath indexes=NSUInteger)0null but patients have 3 objects(which is correcT) and if i drilldown on 0 i see region=(_NSCFString *)@"TEST" which is correct. should note that I have  4 other columns in 0 but only care about 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

patients is an array of Patient instances. You are trying to compare the entire instance to a string which you cannot do. Instead I suspect you want to do:

```
if ([[[patients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] region] isEqualToString:@"test"])
```

Comment: thats kinda what I am actually doing :)

Comment: @Janita No it is not :)

Comment: @Alladinian opps! sorry. I had actually tried that but, it gave the same error